# Get query error message in Mongo Compass

Tags: mongodb-compass

I'm trying to run the following query in MongoDB Compass.
[image: compass_query_bar]

So obviously there is an error with the `project` field but I don't see a way of running the query anyway or to show an error message to help me understand where the problem is.